# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.simple.RealApplication' available

Tags: java, spring-boot, component-scan

I am having trouble understanding on why my Bean `RealApplication` is not registered / found.

File DemoApplication.java:

```
package com.example.simple;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = 
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.refresh();

        RealApplication app = ctx.getBean(RealApplication.class);
        app.run();

        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

File RealApplication.java:

```
package com.example.simple;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RealApplication
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

---

However, strangely, this piece of code works:

File DemoApplication.java:

```
package com.example.simple;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class DemoApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = 
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.example.simple");

        RealApplication app = ctx.getBean(RealApplication.class);
        app.run();

        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

The class RealApplication was unchanged.

Output was:

```
Hello World!
```

My maven pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

For some strange reason, the component-scan is not picking up the RealApplication Bean when i only use the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, even though the two classes are the same package.

But it is able to find it when i specify the package to scan in the constructor to `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you showing the wrong codes ? The codes you show are always creating two application contexts , one is `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and other is created using spring-boot way which involves using `SpringApplication` and `@SpringBootApplication`.

And you always get the `RealApplication` bean from the context created by the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` but not from the context created by the spring boot. To test if the `RealApplication` bean is really created in the latter case , you have to get the bean from the context returned from `SpringApplication.run()`:

```
ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
RealApplication app = context.getBean(RealApplication.class);
app.run();
```

Comment: Thanks, Ken. The problem was that `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()` by itself doesn't register any bean. We need to pass a class which is either a `Configuration` or `Component`. Component-scanning can be triggered by either annotating that class with `ComponentScan` or using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.scan()` or `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("package")`. But you also pointed another issue, in my code, about creating redundant `ApplicationContext`. I am a beginner, so I am accidentally shooting myself in the leg.